# Robolectric 2.4 NoSuchMethodError cannot be cast to RuntimeException when creating activity

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I am starting to use Robolectric in Android Studio. At first I wanted to create a simple test using hamcrest, which is shown below:

```
@RunWith(CustomTestRunner.class)
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
public class MainActivityTest {

    private MainActivity mainActivity;


    @Test
    public void testMainActivity() {
        mainActivity = buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
        assertThat(mainActivity, notNullValue());
    }

}
```

When executing the test throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError cannot be cast to java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.robolectric.internal.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethodReflectively(ReflectionHelpers.java:68)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:115)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:111)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:122)
    at com.enprodo.wakemethere.googleservices.geofence.GeofenceTest.testReceiver(GeofenceTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

The `CustomTestRunner` class looks like this:

```
public class CustomTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public CustomTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
        String manifestProperty = System.getProperty("android.manifest");
        if (config.manifest().equals(Config.DEFAULT) && manifestProperty != null) {
            String resProperty = System.getProperty("android.resources");
            String assetsProperty = System.getProperty("android.assets");
            AndroidManifest androidManifest = new AndroidManifest(
                    Fs.fileFromPath(manifestProperty),
                    Fs.fileFromPath(resProperty),
                    Fs.fileFromPath(assetsProperty));
            androidManifest.setPackageName("com.package");
            return androidManifest;
        }
        return super.getAppManifest(config);
    }
}
```

I can add that MainActivity extends `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` but I have no idea if that affects the behaviour.

After some digging in the Robolectric source it appears the error appears when this is executed:

```
ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethodReflectively(component, "performCreate", new ReflectionHelpers.ClassParameter(Bundle.class, bundle));
```

The code of `callInstanceMethodReflectively` looks like this:

```
  public static <R> R callInstanceMethodReflectively(final Object instance, final String methodName, ClassParameter... classParameters) {
    try {
      final Class[] classes = ClassParameter.getClasses(classParameters);
      final Object[] values = ClassParameter.getValues(classParameters);

      return traverseClassHierarchy(instance.getClass(), NoSuchMethodException.class, new InsideTraversal<R>() {
        @Override
        public R run(Class traversalClass) throws Exception {
          Method declaredMethod = traversalClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, classes);
          declaredMethod.setAccessible(true);
          return (R) declaredMethod.invoke(instance, values);
        }
      });
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      throw (RuntimeException) e.getTargetException();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

I am not a reflection expert, but it seems that somehow the *performCreate* method cannot be found. Has anyone encountered similar issue? Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging it appears that with Robolectric 2.4 some issues with `ActionBarActivity` appear. According to [this issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1446) full support for `appcompat-v7` will be provided in Robolectric 3.0. Indeed trying Robolectric 3.0-SNAPSHOT solved the issue.