# Unit testing with robolectric gives NoSuchMethodException error

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, runtimeexception, nosuchmethoderror

after some time of research I still haven't found out why this thing happens in my Android code. This is just standard simple unit test code, Not much is really going on. I tried this code previously on my work machine and successfully runs the unit test. I don't know why this happens at my other pc at home. Maybe it could be caused by some incorrect setup of robolectric 3, I'm not really sure. I attached the full log report maybe you guys will be able to understand it better. Thanks.

Gradle command to run unit test:

```
gradlew test
```

Error:

```
com.sample.bigger.MainActivityTest > sampleTest FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException                              
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException               
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
```

Full log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.Looper.<init>(boolean)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callConstructor(ReflectionHelpers.java:297)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.createLooper(ShadowLooper.java:43)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.access$000(ShadowLooper.java:25)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper$1.create(ShadowLooper.java:37)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper$1.create(ShadowLooper.java:35)
    at org.robolectric.util.SoftThreadLocal$1.initialValue(SoftThreadLocal.java:13)
    at org.robolectric.util.SoftThreadLocal$1.initialValue(SoftThreadLocal.java:11)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:160)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:150)
    at org.robolectric.util.SoftThreadLocal.get(SoftThreadLocal.java:18)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.resetThreadLoopers(ShadowLooper.java:55)
    at org.robolectric.Shadows.reset(Shadows.java:1612)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.reset(Robolectric.java:22)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.resetStaticState(ParallelUniverse.java:43)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:233)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.Looper.<init>(boolean)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2892)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2058)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callConstructor(ReflectionHelpers.java:283)
    ... 48 more
```

This is my mainActivityTest

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 18)
public class MainActivityTest {

@Test
    public void sampleTest(){
        Assert.assertEquals("hey", "hey");
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.bigger"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Added for AdMob
    compile project(':jokeproviderlib')
    compile project(':jokedisplayer')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile project(path: ':jokeGCMbackend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile 'com.google.mockwebserver:mockwebserver:20130706'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
```

I have seen the following sources, the first seems to be the closest one. I'm still trying how to do it.

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/le1oJKpIW9Q
- [Robolectric 3.0 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException on create activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884419/robolectric-3-0-java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-on-create-activity)
- [Robolectric 2.4 NoSuchMethodError cannot be cast to RuntimeException when creating activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110031/robolectric-2-4)
- nosuchmethoderror-cannot-be-cast-to-runtimeexception-when-creati
- https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1633

Comment: I would remove mockwebserver dependency because you don't want to include it to you application. Everything else looks like simple and valid test that should run. Can you change sdk from 18 to 19? So you have same error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello changing the SDK from 18 to 19 fixed the error. Not really sure what is the cause but the code below now works. Maybe robolectric had dependency trouble when it comes to sdk 18.
Thanks @Eugen

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 19)
public class MainActivityTest {

@Test
    public void sampleTest(){
        Assert.assertEquals("hey", "hey");
    }
}
```

Comment: My error is different from OP, but adding Config annotation and setting sdk version help solved my problem. It's worth to try.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I wrote a testing activity which extends the normal activity inside the test class. and ran into this error.
I moved the testing activity out from the test class, to a separate file, and then it worked out fine.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I kept the class which extends the activity inside the test class, but I changed it to be a static class.  That fixed the problem as well.